# Why is the probability of host opening door $3$ in Monty Hall $1 \over 3$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, monty-hall

I have been told that the probability of the host opening door $3$ in the Monty Hall problem is $1 \over 3$ (a priori, given no other information about what has transpired in the game), but when I tried to verify this myself I got $1 \over 2$ and was wondering what I was doing wrong. Let $C_i$ be the event of the contestant choosing door $i$, $P_i$ the event of the prize being behind door $i$, and $H_i$ the event of the host opening door $i$.
I have computed $\mathbb{P}[H_3]$ as $$\mathbb{P}[H_3\mid C_1 \cap P_1] \cdot\mathbb{P}[C_1 \cap P_1] +  \mathbb{P}[H_3\mid C_1 \cap P_2] \cdot\mathbb{P}[C_1 \cap P_2] + \mathbb{P}[H_3\mid C_2 \cap P_1] \cdot\mathbb{P}[C_2 \cap P_1] + \mathbb{P}[H_3\mid C_2 \cap P_2] \cdot\mathbb{P}[C_2 \cap P_2] = \frac 1 2 
\cdot \frac 1 6 + 1 \cdot \frac 1 6 + 1 \cdot \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 6 = \frac 1 2$$ as $C_i$ and $C_j$ are independent so the probability of their intersection is the product of their probabilities, and I didn't think I needed to subtract anything as $C_i$ and $C_j$ are disjoint for different values of $(i,j)$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: This is missing context.  Are you saying "a priori, before the contestant has chosen a door, and assuming the contestant chooses doors uniformly at random, the probability that Monty will eventually open $\#3$ is $\frac 13$"?  If so, isn't that obvious?  There is symmetry between the three doors.  That is to say, the numbers are irrelevant.  Any path that leads to door $\#n$ being opened could have lead to door $\#3$ being opened, just by re-labeling the doors.

Comment: As to the problem with your method:  For all pairs $i,j$ we have $\mathbb P(C_i\cap P_j)=\frac 19$, not $\frac 16$.  But, really, the symmetry argument is better.

Comment: @lulu could you expand upon the symmetry argument? I see certainly that $1 \over 3$ of the sample points would have door $3$ being opened, that $1 \over 3$ of the sample points have door $2$ being opened, etc. But how would we justify  why opening doors 1,2,3 have equal probabilities, although we could reason that the sample points containing them number the same due to the relabeling argument you mentioned?

Comment: As I mentioned, renaming the doors has no effect on either the contestant's choices, nor on Monty's.  Thus the three doors must have equal chance of being opened.

Comment: It would, of course, be different if the labels did alter the behavior. If, say, contestants strongly preferred to open door $\#2$ for whatever reason, or if, given the option, Monty always preferred to open the higher numbered door.

Comment: Should say:  One needs to make assumptions here.  As I indicated in my first comment, my assumption is that the contestant chooses uniformly between the doors. If, on the other hand, the contestant always chose $\#1$ or if they simply avoid choosing $\#3$ you get a different answer.  The assumptions are critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this problem it is absolutely essential that you describe *exactly* what happens. What actions are forced, which are voluntary, which are based on a strategy with some goal, and so on.

If you don’t do that then you will find all kinds of people coming it with a solution for a problem that is slightly different. And if you got an answer from a book without understanding it, then you will be very frustrated because the problem that you stated and the problem your book solved are not the same and the solutions are not the same.

So please describe *precisely* what you mean by “Monty Hall problem”.